# va_arg returns different values on x86 and ARM

Tags: c++

I'm a new developer on a team who was just given a new Macbook with an M1 Pro (ARM). The rest of my team uses Intel Macbooks (x86). I ran a test which was supposed to create a file and write to it, however, the test errored out because the file was created with incorrect permissions.

I traced it back to a wrapper function that the team uses around `open`, `sysio::openc`. It makes use of a variadic template, and intends to eventually call `open` in libc. Normally, `_syscall(fst, args...)` would be used to call libc's `open`. However, for reasons outside the scope of this question, there is another `open` in available to our test, defined in `our_open.cpp` below, which is called by `_syscall(fst, args...)`. That might make things a bit confusing, but I think it provides valuable debug information.

We've narrowed down the problem to the following:
When debugging on my coworker's Intel (x86) Mac, inside our version of `open`, `mode = va_arg(ap, int)` returns 438 as expected. On my M1 Pro (ARM) Mac, `mode = va_arg(ap, int)` always returns 32.

**Note**

- The same permissions issue occurs if `_syscall(fst, args...)` directly calls libc's version of open instead of our redefined version. I left our redefined version of open in the question because we thought it adds debugging value to be able to look into where `va_arg` is called.
- Replacing our variadic `sysio::openc` wrapper with a direct call to libc's `open` fixes the issue and creates a file with the expected permissions.

It could have something to do with undefined behavior due to an unexpected type being passed to `va_arg` like from [Why va_arg() produce different effects on x86_64 and arm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041919/why-va-arg-produce-different-effects-on-x86-64-and-arm). However, I've experimented with things like `mode_t mode = static_cast<mode_t>(va_arg(ap, int))` with no success. **Also, it wouldn't explain why calling libc's open directly from `_syscall(fst, args...)` (avoiding our use of `va_arg`) still doesn't work.**

<test.cpp>

```
const int fdOut = sysio::openc(path, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_EXCL | O_CLOEXEC, 438);
```

<wrapper.h>

```
template<IOType IOType, typename RetVal, typename... Args>
class IoWrapper
{
public:
    explicit IoWrapper(RetVal syscall(Args...))
      : _syscall(syscall)
    {}

    template<typename Arg1, typename... Ts>
    RetVal operator()(Arg1 fst, Ts... args)
    {
        const RetVal ret = _syscall(fst, args...);
        if (ret == RetVal(-1)) {
            abortOnVfsError<IOType>(fst, errno);
        }

        return ret;
    }

private:
    std::function<RetVal(Args...)> _syscall;
};
template<IOType IOType, typename RetVal, typename... Args>
IoWrapper<IOType, RetVal, Args...> make_wrapper(RetVal syscall(Args...))
{
    return IoWrapper<IOType, RetVal, Args...>(syscall);
}

inline auto openc = make_wrapper<IOType::read>((int (*)(const char*, int, int))::open);
```

<our_open.cpp>

```
extern "C" int open(const char* file, int flags, ...)
{
    static libc_open_ptr libc_open = (libc_open_ptr)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    int mode = 0;
    if ((flags & O_CREAT)) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, flags);
        mode = va_arg(ap, int); // Returns 438 (correct) on x86 but 32 on ARM (M1 Pro)
        va_end(ap);
    }

    return libc_open(file, flags, mode);
}
```

Comment: The linked question is about 32 bit ARM, I don't think it's relevant here (M1 is a 64 bit ARM chip)

Comment: The [Darwin arm64 ABI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-arm64-code-for-apple-platforms) passes all varags arguments on the stack, each padded to the next multiple of 8 bytes. Maybe reading `long` or `long long` and declaring `open(const char* file, long flags, ...)` will help.

Comment: The linked duplicates do not actually address the problem, which is that a `int(const char*, int, ...)` function is being called through a `int (*)(const char*, int, int)`, which is UB. Don't use a cast like that and call the function at its correct type, then it will work. C-style casts strike again!

Comment: @HTNW - the tool is seldom to blame for shoddy craftsmanship.

Comment: `(int (*)(const char*, int, int))::open` will cause undefined behaviour when called, if the function is actually of type `int(*)(const char *, int, ...)`

Comment: If I remove our redefinition of `open`, that means `_syscall(fst, args...)` will be calling the libc version of `open`, which is `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)`. It shouldn't be undefined behavior in that case, correct? It still behaves the same as when using the redefined `open(const char* file, int flags, ...)`, in that it creates a file with mode_t of 32.

Comment: it's UB to call a function through a function pointer of different type

Comment: @tyler124 I'm on a x86 Mac, but `man 2 open` gives me that the system's own `open` is still `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...)`... so no, I would guess your code's broken either way. Basically, if replacing the C-style cast with `static_cast` gives a compiler error, it's your fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to call a function through a function pointer of the wrong type. In this case, `open` has signature `int(const char*, int, ...)` and is being called through a `int (*)(const char*, int, int)`. I would say it's a miracle this code ever works on any architecture! The (IMO quite confusing, consider not using the `::`) syntax `(int (*)(const char*, int, int))::open` is a C-style cast to `int (*)(const char*, int, int)` applied to `::open`. C-style casts are dangerous when used with pointers and references because they suppress warnings about questionable casts. A `static_cast` would have errored here and a `reinterpret_cast` would have at least made you question your choices.

The simplest solution is probably to rely on `std::function` to do the adapting.

```
template<IOType IOType, typename RetVal, typename... Args>
class IoWrapper {
    std::function<RetVal(Args...)> syscall;
public:
    explicit IoWrapper(std::function<RetVal(Args...)> syscall) // function pointers are annoying anyway...
    : syscall(std::move(syscall))
    {}

    template<typename Arg1, typename... Ts>
    RetVal operator()(Arg1 fst, Ts... args) {
        const RetVal ret = syscall(fst, args...);
        if (ret == RetVal(-1)) {
            abortOnVfsError<IOType>(fst, errno);
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
// make_wrapper is unnecessary here because the argument types can't be inferred

inline IoWrapper<IOType::read, int, const char*, int, int> openc(open);
```

Note that BOTH your version of `open` and the standard one in the C library should have the signature `int open(const char*, int, ...)`, hence they *should* either both work or both not work.

Comment: Thanks again. We ended up just removing the wrapper, which overcomplicated things. Also, if you're still a student, your knowledge of C++ is super impressive :)